# Network calling in intent service works only in debug mode

Tags: java, android

Am encountering a strange problem I am trigerring an intent service every 20 sec:
with an api hit through volley
When the app is on  debug mode its working fine and am getting the result. Otherwise its not working at all
Please someone help me tto find a solution for this.

```
public class DataSubmissionService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        gpsTracker_gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext(), Constant.GPS);
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())){
            init();

        }else {
            logUtils.writeToLogFile("Network not available");
        }
    }

    private void fetchinfofromTracker(GPSTracker gpsTracker) {
        latitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
        Log.d(TAG, "Latitude :" + latitude);
        longitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);
        Log.d(TAG, "Longitude :" + longitude);

        elevation = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.altitude);
        speed = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.speed);
        accuracy = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.accuracy);
        provider = gpsTracker.provider;
        bearing = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.bearing);

        model.setLatitude(latitude);
        model.setLongitude(longitude);
        model.setAccuracy(accuracy);
        model.setProvider(provider);
        model.setBearing(bearing);
        model.setTimeStamp(getCurrentDateTime());
        // callAlarmManager();

        // logUtils.logText("GPS Values:" + "Latitude" +latitude + " Longitude" + longitude );
        if (latitude.equals("0.0")) {
            latitude = "0.0";
            longitude = "0.0";
            model.setLatitude(latitude);
            model.setLongitude(longitude);
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
            intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
            intent.putExtra("speed", speed);
            intent.putExtra("accuracy", accuracy);
            intent.putExtra("bearing", bearing);
            intent.putExtra("provider", provider);
            intent.putExtra("elevation", elevation);
            sendBroadcast(intent);

            // insertdata();
            sendToServer(model);
        }
    }

    private void sendVolleyRequest(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            logUtils.logText("Connecting to server");
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String URL = Constant.BASE_URL;
            JSONObject jsonBody = jsonObject;
            final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        // display response
                        responseListener(response.toString(),resultCode);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                        logUtils.writeToLogFile(error.toString());
                    }
                }
        ){
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        getRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                TIME_OUT,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(getRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  public void responseListener(String res, int resultCode) {
    Log.e(TAG,res);
    //Log.e("responseFromFeecal..", res);
    //Log.e("feeResultCode", "" + resultCode);
    //Log.e("CMR", "Server response: " + res);
    int maxLogSize = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i <= res.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
        int start = i * maxLogSize;
        int end = (i + 1) * maxLogSize;
        end = end > res.length() ? res.length() : end;
        Log.v("lt_response", res.substring(start, end));
    }
    logUtils.logText("Server Response: " + res);
    if (res.contains("100") || (res.contains("Success"))) {
       /* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        String guidval = "";
        String status = "";
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(res);
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray idStr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ReceivedGuidKeys");

            JSONObject key_value = idStr.getJSONObject(0);
            String key_c = key_value.getString("key");
            guidval = key_c;
            String status_c = key_value.getString("status");
            status = status_c;
            System.out.println("Status: " + status_c + " GUIDKey: " + key_c);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logUtils.logText(e.getMessage());
        }

        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.FALSE)) {
            //SendtoServer(guidval, Constant.PENDINGITEM);
            logUtils.logText("Server returns false for " + guidval);
            System.out.print("Server returns false for " + guidval);
        }
    } else {
        /*DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        db.logRecordCounts();*/
        logUtils.logText("Server failed to respond");
    }
}
}
```

While am working on debugging , all the time its hitting the api and giving me the perfect response

Comment: On which OS version are you running your test?

Comment: It is on 5.1.1, Its  working on debugging mode

Comment: Please add responseListener method

Comment: Edited with the data